# Rails : RuntimeError - can't modify frozen Array when running rspec in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I recently upgraded to Rails 5.1 from v4.3 and am now getting this error when running tests:

```
An error occurred while loading 

./spec/controllers/admin/capacity_charges_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

RuntimeError:
  can't modify frozen Array
```

I get it for every test file. The line that triggers the error comes from rails_helper. I've checked rails 5.1 sample repos and there's nothing substantially different about our version.

The full stack trace is:

```
RuntimeError:


can't modify frozen Array
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/actionpack-5.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:74:in `insert'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/actionpack-5.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:74:in `insert'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/actionpack-5.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:81:in `insert_after'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/request_store-1.3.2/lib/request_store/railtie.rb:5:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
# ./spec/controllers/admin/capacity_charges_controller_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
# /Users/jeremynagel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@Rails4.2_EnergyLink/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
```

Answer (score 67):

Turns out this was caused by test failures higher in the stack trace. It was hard to see what the root cause was because there was so much in the console. If you get this issue, I'd suggest using `--fail-fast` so you don't get overwhelmed with recurrent error messages. Then check what the first error is.

Comment: pg connection in my case :)

Comment: I had a duplicate factory generator name in my factory_bot spec, which caused this

Comment: I had a file `foo/bar.rb` which did not define the constant `Foo::Bar` in my case. This only failed with activated eager loading.

Comment: Yeah, this error is horrible. Every time I mess up renaming a file or renaming a `require path` somewhere I get this error. And then good luck finding this one-letter typo somewhere in hundreds of my files.

Comment: `--fail-fast` didn't work, but piping the output into `more` worked fine. Turns out I had some duplicated traits in my FactoryBot file.

Comment: For me, the issue was that I was running all my specs. When I ran the spec for a single file, it gave a much more clear error message ( bundle exec rspec spec/models/some_model_spec.rb)

Comment: This is an alternative to spot the problem `rspec --fail-fast | head`

Comment: Still an issue, solved by `rspec --fail-fast | head`. Anyone know **why** this happens? Can we fix it?

Answer (score 13):

For me it was a *FactoryBot* update from version `4` to `5`. I didn't see the deprecation warning because I jumped versions:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Static attributes will be removed in FactoryBot 5.0.
```

Comment: this worked for me as well

changing `last_name "Lincoln"` to `last_name { "Lincoln" }` in the /spec/factories resolved the frozen array error

Answer (score 11):

I did `rspec | less` to find the first error

Answer (score 8):

Check that your Test DB is up to date before anything else.

rake db:test:prepare.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes this exception is also raised if you have a wrong class name inheritance in your Ruby classes.  Remember that controllers, models, etc, are all constants in Ruby.

This is an example off the top-of-my-head of a situation I encountered.  Actual syntax may be off, but this was the concept that caused my problem.

```
module Admin
  class BaseController < ::ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end

# throws error, referencing constant that does not exist.
# Should be < ::Admin::BaseController
class OtherController < ::BaseController
end
```

Like others, my entire `rspec` suite would fail with the error `can't modify a frozen Array`, which isn't a very helpful stacktrace in this instance, per se.

Hope this save someone else from spending hours hunting down everything else!

Comment: How did you track down the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I'll post my cause, but first I'll post a troubleshooting path to help *you* find *your* cause, as this error can show up for a myriad of reasons.

This is a fairly useless error in most contexts, and the stack trace is impenetrable. I've examined all the gem code in the stack, and none of it points to the actual source of the problem:

```
# /Users/dh/.gem/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:76:in `insert'
# /Users/dh/.gem/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:76:in `insert'
# /Users/dh/.gem/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:83:in `insert_after'
# /Users/dh/.gem/gems/request_store-1.4.1/lib/request_store/railtie.rb:5:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
# /Users/dh/.gem/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
# /Users/dh/.gem/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
# /Users/dh/.gem/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
# /Users/dh/.gem/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
# /Users/dh/.gem/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

To track down why you're getting this error, first comment out (or change back) whatever you did last and see if the problem goes away. If not, restore that line of code, then `git stash` to hide *all* your recent changes and run tests.

That will probably fix the issue, and you can `git stash pop` and start dividing your changes in half until you identify where the problem is.

If `git stash` does not fix the issue, then you know the problem is either external to your code, or was present in your last commit.

If you know your previous commit tested clean, start looking at your databases, bundle your gems, changes to ENV vars you use, or other environmental factors your app depends on.

If `git stash` did *not* fix the problem, and you don't know if your last commit was previously testing clean, start digging back through your commits, either manually or with `git bisect`. If you can find a commit that started breaking tests, you'll be able to track down the line that is triggering this error.

--

As for my particular issue, it was a typo in a new `has_many` relationship I added:

```
  has_many :marijunas, class_name: Drug
```

Once I narrowed down the change to that line, the fix became obvious:

```
  has_many :marijunas, class_name: :Drug
```

Comment: Fun project you're up to! :)

Comment: Can I collab on this project? ;P

Answer (score 2):

When i got the same error with similar stacktrace, it helped me to fix a syntax error in factories.

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone in future, it was database connection issue (Postgresql in my case). Head over to `config/database.yml` file and supply `username:`  and `password:` < default is *toor*>

Add this in the `development:` group.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: try loading the app in development after adding `config.eager_load = true` to your development.rb file, which should give you an actually useful error message pinpointing the problem code.

In my case, a Rails 5.2 app, it was purely a result of upgrading from Ruby 2.4.5 to 2.5.8 which pinpointed the sole issue was `unmatched range specifier in char-class` in a very long regex that has been working for years.

Answer (score 2):

I think when i had similar problem, it was due to syntax error. Try to run rails db:migrate to show more information on the line where error occur

Answer (score 2):

It was because I forgot to add `bullet` to the `test` group in `Gemfile`, looking at the top of the errors I saw:

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant Bullet
```

Comment: This was my issue as well. Current instructions for bullet only suggest it be added to the "development" group.

Answer (score 1):

In my case recent rails_admin required some addition

> RuntimeError:   Required middlewares for RailsAdmin are not added
>   To fix tihs, add
>
> ```
> config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
> ```
>
> to config/application.rb.

Then all rspecs became green again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to a git conflict message (the one like `>>>> ... === ... <<<<`) that I missed to resolve, so there was a syntax error when Rspec has been trying to load that class.

`--fail-fast` command line option does not help in this case as the error happens higher in the call stack, but you can see the actual error by just running any single spec file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when working on an application with **Rails 6**.

The issue was that when I ran the command `rspec` I get the error below. The output below is shortened:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/routing/applyportal/school_histories_routing_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

FrozenError:
  can't modify frozen Array: ["/home/promisechukwuenyem/Projects/myapp/app/channels",
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was a result of errors in my code after I did a git pull.

Since I was running in development, I tried dropping my database using:

```
rails db:drop
```

**Note**: This did not drop my database, as the command was interrupted by the error in my code.

And then the actual place where the error was showed up in my terminal which was my `config/route.rb` file.

I had open my `config/route.rb` file. And then I found this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
<<<<<<< HEAD
  resources :courses
=======
  resources :results
>>>>>>> Added result and result upload feature
  resources :books
  resources :schools
end
```

And then modified it to this:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books
  resources :results
  resources :schools
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it turned out to be an issue with a `config.after_initialize` block failure, hidden during a `rspec` run.

However, the error surfaced when I called `$ rails c -e test`. Hope this helps someone with this being my first post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update from Rails 3 to Rails 5.
I just set `config.eager_load` option and it helped. Either to `false` or `true`. Not `nil`, please

Answer (score 0):

My two-cents, as it may help someone else.   I had this same issue when upgrading `rails 4.2` to `5.0`  I saw a thread post somewhere that suggested running one spec-test by itself / at a time.  When I did that, I got a different error: `superclass must be a Class` and pointed me to my new `.../models/application_record.rb` file, in which I had made a syntax error by omission:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord                              
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

The above is missing `::Base` after `ActiveRecord` -- first line.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base                                
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Adding that back in fixed all my specs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `config.eager_load = true` in your environment file. This will load all files in memory during boot & will point out existing syntax errors in first place if any.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I removed the gem 'Faker' but left the `require 'faker'` inside factories.rb

Answer (score -2):

Try to run redis and sidekiq on background. In my case it was one of reasons.