# RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array (Rollbar, Rails 5.1 upgrade)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rollbar

Unable to use rspec and rollbar after upgrading to rails 5.

1. Create a Rails 4 app
2. Upgrade gemfile to use rails 5
3. Try adding rollbar gem/support

Standard config/environment.rb:

```
 # Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Error when running rspec:

```
An error occurred while loading {path to specific spec file}
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

RuntimeError:
  can't modify frozen Array
# ./config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
...
No examples found.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In most cases, that error is a red herring for something else.

When encountering it, don't get overwhelmed with the recurrent `can't modify frozen Array` error messages, and instead check the very first error that appears when running a spec.

For example:

> Failure/Error: validate :uniqueness, if: 'should_be_unique?'
>
> ArgumentError:   Passing string to be evaluated in :if and :unless
> conditional options is not supported. Pass a symbol for an instance
> method, or a lambda, proc or block, instead.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. How did you find the first error. I am seeing the same error but can't see any other errors.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me likely hours of head-desk interactions.

Comment: Bless you. :raised_hands:

Comment: Thank you. Upvote for you. FWIW rspec `--fail-early` didn't show the first error. I ran `rspec > output.txt` and viewed the top of the txt file to see the first error

Answer (score 6):

Just to add one tip on top of [Maxximo Mussini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/747418/maximo-mussini)'s answer.

If anyone can't find the first error on the terminal, please try to run RSpec on one file, i.e. `rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb`

You should be able to find the root case.

In my case, I haven't updated my local `.env` variables that is required by `User` model

Hope it helps

Comment: This is helpful, but should probably be a comment on the answer you're referring to, not its own answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @GregJackson but I don't have 50 reputation to comment on Maximo answer.
Really sorry for this

Answer (score -3):

Debugging this is not easy but one possible solution is simple. It could be a naming conflict with Rollbar, possibly something getting monkey-patched. If you're seeing this RuntimeError but not using Rollbar, see other answer.

Add a **Module** ("namespace" of your choice) around your app class definition in `config/application.rb`.

The module won't affect much. The only difference I could find is when printing out your app it will now appear as (that's how we found the fix vs a new working app):

`<MyTestAPP::Application ...>` instead of `<Application ...>`

Change:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1
  end
```

To:

```
Module MyTestApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1
  end
end
```